# Special For-Loop in Pascal

Tags: loops, for-loop, pascal

I work with a current software for the simulation of power plant processes. Smaller scripts can be written within the software for automation, these scripts are based on Pascal and own function libraries. Was simply retained after the initial release 20 years ago.
My simple script transfers values from one element to another and has this structure:

```
var f: integer;

S13Be.MXTSTO.data(1,1) := 22;
S12Be.MXTSTO.data(1,S12Be.NFLOW) := 22;
S11Be.MXTSTO.data(1,1) := S12Be.MXTSTO.data(1,S12Be.NFLOW);
S10Be.MXTSTO.data(1,S10Be.NFLOW) := 22;
S9Be.MXTSTO.data(1,1) := S10Be.MXTSTO.data(1,S10Be.NFLOW);
S8Be.MXTSTO.data(1,S8Be.NFLOW) := 22;
S7Be.MXTSTO.data(1,1) := S8Be.MXTSTO.data(1,S8Be.NFLOW);    
S5Be.MXTSTO.data(1,S5Be.NFLOW) := 22;   
S4Be.MXTSTO.data(1,1) := S5Be.MXTSTO.data(1,S4Be.NFLOW);
S2Be.MXTSTO.data(1,S2Be.NFLOW) := 22;
S1Be.MXTSTO.data(1,1) := S2Be.MXTSTO.data(1,S4Be.NFLOW);

for f := 1 to S13Be.NFLOW+1 do begin
  S13Be.MXTSTO.data(1,f) := S13Be.MXTSTO.data(1,1);
end;
for f := 1 to S12Be.NFLOW+1 do begin
  S12Be.MXTSTO.data(1,f) := S12Be.MXTSTO.data(1,1);
end;
for f := 1 to S11Be.NFLOW+1 do begin
  S11Be.MXTSTO.data(1,f) := S11Be.MXTSTO.data(1,1);
end;
```

.
.
.

```
for f := 1 to S2Be.NFLOW+1 do begin
  S2Be.MXTSTO.data(1,f) := S2Be.MXTSTO.data(1,1);
end;
for f := 1 to S1Be.NFLOW+1 do begin
  S1Be.MXTSTO.data(1,f) := S1Be.MXTSTO.data(1,1);
end;
```

I would like to put another loop around the outside so that the elements are automatically selected.
The names of the elements are S1Be, S2Be.... S13Be and S1Ent, S2Ent, S3Ent...S13Ent
.MXSTO.data accesses a matrix in the respective element
(1,f) defines the position in the matrix (currently there are only 1x5 and 1x10 matrices; the value .NFLOW specifies which matrix is involved.)

I would be very grateful for a tip, a book recommendation and of course a code.

With best regards

Felix

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: This is generally not possible in Pascal, though it could theoretically be permitted if your Pascal processor is an interpreter rather than a compiler, and has an instruction that is equivalent to the PowerShell `Invoke-Expression` or APL's `⍎`

Comment: Also, for future reference, asking for a *book recommendation* or other off-site resource is specifically off-topic here according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Names generally no meaning in a compiled program, it doesn't contain them.

If the identifiers are the same type you might be able to define an array of pointers to them, and then iterate using that array.

Comment: This is the help of the software I use. Maybe it can help to understand and solve my problem. https://help.ebsilon.com/EN/webframe.html#Ebscript.html

Comment: Sorry, don't know that one. See if it supports pointers.

Comment: Enumerated types

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled with an enumerated type. The solution will require a little reorganization of your date, but I think it will be worth it. Like most languages variables are independent of each other. If you want to deal with a list of variables they will need to be in a structure of some sort. An array in your case makes sense. However, associating a numeric index with each variable is a bother and requires pointers or some difficult to maintain parsing system.

Nicklaus Wirth created a mechanism to deal with this sort of problem. It is called an enumerated type.  For example:

```
type
    BeName = (S1Be, S2Be, S3Be, S4Be);      
var
    NFLOW: array[BeName] of integer;
    MXTSTOdata: array[BeName,1:5,1:10] of integer;
    SnBe: BeName;
begin
… Initialization here, the following is how to change your code.
MXTSTOdata(S2Be,1,NFLOW[S2Be]) := 22;
MXTSTOdata(S1Be,1,1) :=MXTSTOdata(S2Be,1,NFLOW[S4Be]);

… Here is just one for loop:
for f := 1 to NFLOW[S1Be]+1 do
    MXTSTOdata[S1Be,1,f] := MXTSTOdata[S1Be,1,1];
… Here is a loop of for loops:
for SnBe := S1Be to S4Be do
    for f := 1 to NFLOW[SnBe]+1 do
        MXTSTOdata[SnBe,1,f] := MXTSTOdata[SnBe,1,1];
```

Note how the for loop doesn’t need a start and end index. But that depends on which Pascal you are using. Delphi, FreePascal, and standard Pascal differ. You might have to use the first and last element like I showed. You might have a Low and High function available.

```
var
    NFLOW: array[BeName] of integer;
    SnBe: BeName;
for SnBe := Low(BeName) to High(BeName) do
    for f := 1 to NFLOW[SnBe]+1 do
        MXTSTOdata[SnBe,1,f] := MXTSTOdata[SnBe,1,1];
```

And I might have the syntax for the array declaration wrong. I’ve seen  var NFLOW: array of [BeName] of integer; documented on the web, built I haven’t fired up my pascal compiler to check this fragment. However, the enumeration type would help you a lot. Also, there is a for-in construct in FreePascal

```
for SnBe in BeName do
    for f := 1 to NFLOW[SnBe]+1 do
        MXTSTOdata[SnBe,1,f] := MXTSTOdata[SnBe,1,1];
```

The enumeration type is useful in preventing bothersome minor spelling errors from messing up the program, has nice for loop options, and can change the ordering of the values in the enumeration. Changing the ordering may be needed for handling what order assignments are made in, at the cost of program fragility, as you might imagine.

The pred and succ operators are implemented. If you ever wondered what the need were for pred and succ you have now found out. A while loop:

```
SnBe := S1Be;
repeat
    … something
    SnBe := succ(SnBe)
    until SnBe = S4Be;
```

Of course that doesn’t get easily to the last value in the enumeration. You could add guard values, but that adds some confusion and messes up the for-in loop.

```
SnBe := S1Be;
repeat
    SomefunctionF(SnBe);
    SnBe := succ(SnBe)
    until SnBe = S4Be;
SomefunctionF(S4Be);
```

Is probably the cleanest way to deal with the problem of running in a repeat loop. The reason for adding these examples is you may have two enumerations running in parallel:

```
type
    ToBeName = (S1Be, S2Be, S3Be, S4Be);  
    NotToBeName = (Bob, Carol, Ted, Alice);    
var
    NFLOW: array[BeName] of integer;
    MXTSTOdata: array[BeName,1:5,1:10] of integer;
    Romeo: NotToBeName;
    SnBe: BeName;
begin
SnBe:=S1Be;
Romeo:=Bob;
Repeat
    ActionFunction(SnBe,Romeo);
    SnBe := succ(SnBe);
    Romeo := succ(Romeo)
    until SnBe = Alice;
```

Also, this idea might be helpful for your program:

```
type
    EType = (S1Be, S2Be, S3Be, S4Be, Bob, Carol, Ted, Alice);    
var
    Romeo: EType;
    SnBe: EType;
begin
Romeo:= Bob;
SnBe:=S1Be;
repeat 
     SomeFn(Romeo,SnBe);
     SnBe:=succ(SnBe);
     until SnBe>S4Be;
```

The range check applies to pred and succ. For example, the statement

```
succ(Alice)
```

would produce an error because there is no element after Alice in the enumerations above.

Lastly, if you need to do things in reverse order you can do:

```
for SnBe := S4Be downto S1Be do
```